# Make logo form appear in installation page

Tags: 7

I wrote the following function, but it doesn't work. It expects parameters. How do I correct this function ?

```
function store_install_tasks() {
  module_load_include('inc', 'system', 'system.admin');

  $tasks = array('system_theme_settings' => array(
    'display_name' => st('File Settings'),
    'display' => TRUE,
    'type' => 'form',
    'run' => INSTALL_TASK_RUN_IF_NOT_COMPLETED,
  ));
  return $tasks;
}
```

Error

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in system_theme_settings() (line 396 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in system_theme_settings() (line 396 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in system_theme_settings() (line 434 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in system_theme_settings() (line 434 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in system_theme_settings() (line 434 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in system_theme_settings() (line 434 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in system_theme_settings() (line 434 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in system_theme_settings() (line 434 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in system_theme_settings() (line 434 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in system_theme_settings() (line 434 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in system_theme_settings() (line 434 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in system_theme_settings() (line 450 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in system_theme_settings() (line 493 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: Illegal offset type in system_theme_settings() (line 535 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in system_theme_settings() (line 535 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: Illegal offset type in system_theme_settings() (line 546 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: Illegal offset type in system_theme_settings() (line 563 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in system_theme_settings() (line 563 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\system\system.admin.inc).
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in color_get_info() (line 120 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\modules\color\color.module).
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in drupal_get_filename() (line 847 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\includes\bootstrap.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2135 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\includes\database\database.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2135 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\includes\database\database.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2135 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\includes\database\database.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2135 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\includes\database\database.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2135 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\includes\database\database.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2135 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\includes\database\database.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in DatabaseStatementBase->execute() (line 2135 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\includes\database\database.inc).
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in drupal_get_filename() (line 870 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\includes\bootstrap.inc).
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in drupal_get_filename() (line 901 of C:\wamp\www\drupal4\includes\bootstrap.inc).
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Please post the error-message

Comment: @Michiel - See my question now

Comment: What are you trying to do with the function?

Comment: @Michiel - I just want to bring the amin settings logo page over here i.e. installation profile page

Comment: You want to set the logo image as part of the installation phase? I suggest you look at the docs for hook_install_tasks() http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks/7

Comment: @paul-m  - yup.correct.